# How is the Shift Lock light wired?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, hardware-failure, shift

I have had a problem with my laptop keyboard for months now. In short, it starts and stops working with little or no warning, and when it works, it has some strange glitches. I assumed a faulty wire, but I noticed something: Even when the keyboard is unresponsive, using a USB keyboard and pressing Shift Lock makes the Shift Lock light turn on and off -on the inactive keyboard-. Is the light a separate wire from the key sensor, or is this a bigger mystery than first expected?

(I have posted about the keyboard glitch before, with no solution, but this is specifically about the Shift Lock light)

Comment: On my machines, past and present; laptop or desktop, shift, num, caps lights are part of the keyboard and then run by the OS (not separable).

Answer (score 1):

Wiring for the Capslock, Numlock and Scroll lock vary from model to model, so it might be that in your case its not exactly as depicted in this answer. Its up to the manufacturer of the keyboard to decide how they deal with it. But in general, this answer seems to hold true in most of the cases.

The reason for these lights to exist is because early keyboards had a 2 state CapsLock, Scroll lock and Numlock. There were no lights. You pressed it down and it stayed pressed until pressed again. The state was visible by the naked eye.

This was replaced for keys you press but don't stick, and required an indicator light to tell if its pressed or not.

Although the keyboard itself will still internally turn the lights on and off during a keypress, keyboards allow the state of the lights to be controlled on a driver level too.

This allows programs to change the state of a key without requiring the user to actually press the key themselves, eg. to set Capslock to off on a password field, or to use Scroll lock as an indicator light (looking at you, C64 emulator)

Because the light on USB keyboards is software controlled, some keyboards will not function until the drivers have been initialized, so its not a true hardware light.

So long story short: Both the physical keys and the driver talk to the controller and can toggle the state of the Caps Lock, Num Lock and Scroll Lock, and the controller then changes the light of the key on or off to indicate its state.

Dave`s Garage from Microsoft made [a really good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJ0U8RmW-oE) about this subject'

Comment: But if the keyboard seizes to work because of hardware failure, would the light still work when the key does not? Also, Dave is adorable!

Comment: That really depends on how the keyboard seizes to work. If the wire from the controller to the mainboard stops working correctly, but the keyboard to the led works correctly, you get the behavior you describe.